# Is it safe to create python virtualenv to /usr/share/?

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-venv, debian-packaging

I've been working on building debian package of my project.

When user installs my package, then my project's binaries are installed on `/usr/bin/*`. And then, a bash script is invoked at the end that creates python virtual environment to `/usr/share/my_proejct/venv` and installs required python package on that virtual environment.

```sh
$ sudo dpkg -i my_project.deb
# being installed on /usr/bin/*
# automatically `sudo post_install.sh` is invoked(debian postinst)
$ cat post_install.sh
python3 -m pip install -U virtualenv        # sudo
python3 -m venv /usr/share/my_project/venv  # sudo
/usr/share/my_project/venv/bin/python -m pip install ${REQUIRED_PACKAGES}
```

And my project's binaries are using that virtual environment's python.

1. AFAIK, running pip with sudo has security problem. But I just use virtualenv's python( `/usr/share/my_project/venv/bin/python`) directly;I still install `virtualenv` with sudo and create `venv` with it. Is it still dangerous?
2. Can I use this virtual environment's python with multiple users?